# django list view with first and last special

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am displaying a list view in a django template, I'd like to have the first and last elements displayed use different CSS classes than the interior elements.

I can do this by taking a slice on the python side and passing in `list_of_things` (the slice, which omits the first and last elements), `first_in_list`, and `last_in_list`.  I can do the same on the template side with `{% list_of_elements|slice %}`, `{% list_of_elements|first %}`, `{% list_of_elements|last %}`.  But both seem inelegant, since they require me to repeat the html line three times (for interior, first, and last).

What I'd like is a template-side test so that I can `{% if ... %}` for just the parts that change.  Does this exist?  Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could inline your if-statements:

```
<ul>
  {% for e in list_of_elements %}
    <li class='{% if forloop.first %}first{% endif %}{% if forloop.last %}last{% endif %}'>{{ e }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Edit: line breaks for readability:

```
<ul>
  {% for e in list_of_elements %}
    <li class='{% if forloop.first %}first{% endif %}
               {% if forloop.last %}last{% endif %}'>
      {{ e }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Right!  I didn't know about the forloop.first (etc.) tags.  I see them in the docs now, and that's exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use just CSS for that, no Django or template code.

Table example

tr:nth-last-child(1) {
  ⋮ declarations
}

List example

li:first-child {
  ⋮ declarations
}

etc...

Comment: But I have to know where I am in the loop to know which CSS style to indicate, no?  Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: You misunderstood. This CSS is just painting the first or the last element rendered, of any list. It will also work if you fetched more elements than visually listed, which would break previous solution.